# Spring security ldap ad authentication

Tags: java, spring-security, ldap

I am trying to authenticate to an ldap server using spring security 3.1.

I have zero to very little knowledge of ldap.

In the old code  , which is around 7years old. we have a servlet calling a login object as

```
  mypackage.Login login = new mypackage.Login("*******",
                          "389",
                          "none",
                          "cn",
                          "ou=Employees, ou=**, o=ny, c=US",
                          "ou=Employees, ou=**, o=ny, c=US",
                          v);
   String[] res = login.authenticate(username, password);
```

The Login code is as:

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import javax.naming.*;
import javax.naming.directory.*;
import mypackage.LoginErrorBean;

import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class Login 
{
  private static String INITCTX = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";

  private String host;
  private String port;
  private String encryption;
  private String mgrdnattrib;
  private String mgrdnpath;
  private String searchbase;
  private Vector attribs;

  private LoginErrorBean myErrors = new LoginErrorBean();

  public Login() {}

  public Login(String host,String port,String encryption,String mgrdnattrib,String mgrdnpath,String searchbase,Vector attribs) 

  {
    // Parameter settings to connect to desired LDAP service.
    // Note: the encryption piece does not seem to work at all
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    this.encryption = encryption;
    this.mgrdnattrib = mgrdnattrib;
    this.mgrdnpath = mgrdnpath;
    this.searchbase = searchbase;
    this.attribs = attribs;
  }

  public String[] authenticate(String username, String password) throws NamingException
  {
     String[] authenticate;
          authenticate = new String [5];

    //Set default authentication code to false, f. Authentication is considered valid if value other than 'f' is returned for [0]
          authenticate[0] = "f";

    try {
      String MGR_DN = mgrdnattrib + "="  + username.toUpperCase() + "," + mgrdnpath;
      String MGR_PW = password;
      String provider = "ldap://" + host + ":" + port;

      // Parse atributes
      String MY_ATTRS[] = new String[attribs.size()];
      for (int i = 0; i < attribs.size(); ++i) {MY_ATTRS[i] = (String)attribs.get(i);}

      // Specify the search filter to match for general users
      String MY_FILTER ="("+ mgrdnattrib+"=*)";

      Hashtable env = new Hashtable();

      // Specify which class to use for our JNDI provider
      env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
      env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, provider);
      env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple");
      env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,MGR_DN);
      env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,MGR_PW);

      if ( encryption.toUpperCase().compareTo("SSL") == 0 ) {env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL,"ssl");}

      // Specify host and port to use for directory service

      // Get a reference to a directory context
      DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

      // Specify the scope of the search
      SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
      constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

      // Perform the actual search
      // We give it a searchbase, a filter and a the constraints
      // containing the scope of the search
      NamingEnumeration results = ctx.search(searchbase,MY_FILTER, constraints);

      Attribute fn = null;
      Attribute last = null;
      Attributes res = null;
      Attribute ou = null;
      Attribute tel = null;
      Attribute rm = null;
      String givenname = "";
      String ln = "";
      String area = "";
      String phone = "";
      String room = "";

        if (results != null && results.hasMore()) {

          SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) results.next();

          //Attempt to retrieve the ou
          try 
          {  res = sr.getAttributes();
             ou = res.get("ou");
             area = ou.toString();            
          } catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();} 
          finally {}

          area.trim();

          //Given name
          try 
          { fn = res.get("givenname");
            givenname = fn.toString();
            givenname = givenname.replaceAll("givenName:","");
            givenname = givenname.trim();
            authenticate[1]=givenname;
          } catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();} 
          finally {}

          //sn
          try 
          { last = res.get("sn");
            ln = last.toString();
            ln = ln.replaceAll("sn:","");
            ln = ln.trim();
            authenticate[2]= ln;
          } catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();} 
          finally {}

          //Phone
          try 
          { tel = res.get("telephonenumber");
            phone = (tel.toString()==null?"No Phone":tel.toString());
            if(phone.length()==0)
            {phone="telephoneNumber:None";}
          phone = phone.replaceAll("telephoneNumber:","");
          phone = phone.trim();
          authenticate[3]= phone;
          } catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();} 
          finally {}

          //Room
          try 
          { rm = res.get("l");
            room = rm.toString();
           if(room.length()==0)
            {room="l:None";}
          room = room.replaceAll("l:","");
          room = room.trim();
          authenticate[4]= room;
          } catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();} 
          finally {}
          authenticate [0] = "u";
          /**
           * This section appears to check again, confirming that the username for login is the same login name found in LDAP. 
           * It seems like this is repetitive, will maintain for now however. 10/30/06 axk
          */

      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        authenticate[1] = e.getMessage();
        myErrors.addErrorMessage(e.toString());

    }
    return authenticate;
  }
}
```

I am trying to do this in spring security file as:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:s="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <s:http auto-config="true">
                <s:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
                <s:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
                <s:intercept-url pattern="/" access="ROLE_USER" />       
        <s:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/getemp"/>
        <s:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </s:http>

    <s:authentication-manager>


                        <s:authentication-provider ref="adAuthenticationProvider"/>


    </s:authentication-manager>


      <bean id="adAuthenticationProvider"
  class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg value="*********" />
    <constructor-arg value="************" />
    <property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true"/>
</bean>       
</beans>
```

The html login page that shows is:

#### Login with Username and Password (Custom Page)

```
    <form method="POST" action="j_spring_security_check" name="f">

        <table>
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" name="j_username">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="j_password">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="reset" name="reset">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>

    </form>

</body>
```

Earlier I was trying filterbasedLdapAuthenticator ann was atleast getting an exception. Now when I try to login: nothing shows up on the console - I get the login page again.
Where could I be going wrong.

Comment: Enable debug logging for Spring Security and it'll tell you exactly why authentication fails.

Answer (score 1):

To see if there was some exception during the login add the following to your jsp.

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.login_error}">
  <font color="red">
    Your login attempt was not successful, try again.<br/><br/>
    Reason: <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}"/>.
  </font>
</c:if>
```

This must also be added to your spring security file.

```
<s:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/getemp" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=1"/>
```

One other thing to check is that the roles that ldap is returning has the ROLE_USER.  If you don't need a specific role then change your intercept url to just check for isAuthenticated().

```
<s:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
```

Comment: Thanks .. that helped. I do not get any exception or error on the console , but on the front end , I am getting the last_security_exception_message as "BAD credentials". Now the username , password i am entering is correct. The username I am entering here is the uid and also the cn of the entry in LDAP.

Comment: Looking at your old code it looks like you may not be using active directory.  There may be another type of ldap server you may be using.  To set the options that you are trying to setup you may want to use the <ldap-authentication-provider tag in the authentication manager.  This will give you the option to setup the options you need like the ou.  An example of this is at http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ldap.html#d0e6466.